# 8051 reset vector points to non-existent memory?

Tags: 8051

I'm trying to understand my car radio, it's a Becker BE2580 as used in Alfa Romeo 166.

The processor used is an 80C535 from Siemens, 8051 compatible.

I've dumped the 8kb eprom.

0x000-0x1fff addressable.

As far as I understand, a power-on-reset reads the vector at 0x0000 which is 0xC0D0, and then starts executing the code from that location.

However, this address doesn't exist. (neither does 0xD0C0, for that matter)

included are the first 0x0f bytes:

```
                        
       CODE:0000  c0              ??         C0h
       CODE:0001  d0              ??         D0h
       CODE:0002  70              ??         70h    p
       CODE:0003  03              ??         03h
       CODE:0004  e9              ??         E9h
       CODE:0005  80              ??         80h
       CODE:0006  08              ??         08h
       CODE:0007  50              ??         50h    P
       CODE:0008  03              ??         03h
       CODE:0009  29              ??         29h    )
       CODE:000a  80              ??         80h
       CODE:000b  03              ??         03h
       CODE:000c  c9              ??         C9h
       CODE:000d  c3              ??         C3h
       CODE:000e  99              ??         99h
       CODE:000f  c3              ??         C3h
```

My question: which address contains the first valid instruction?

Please feel free to enlighten me, but since these are my first (baby-)steps in this field, try to be gentle.

Thank you.

I've confirmed A0-A12 from the eprom to the processor are connected in a non-obfuscated way.
(i.e directly) therefore the databits are also 1:1.

Answer (score 0):

The 8051 microcontrollers directly start at address 0. It is not a vector at that address.